# getting data of submitted file using jquery ajax and handling It with ModelForm

Tags: python, django, jquery

I'm going to edit an ImageField using jquery ajax,after searching I found out I should use jquery form plugin,so I think using introduced method in this article is good : http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/upload-to-django-with-progress-bar-using-ajax-and-jquery/
But I wanna get data of POST image and give it to a model form to handle It,because It take care of every thing,even when the name of file is repeated,some thing like this:

```
<form id='form_upload' action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' id='id_HeadImage' />
</form>
<script typr="text/javascript">    
var options = {
      dataType: 'xml',
      url: '{% url DrHub.views.editNews param1,param2 %}',
      beforeSubmit: showRequest,
      success: showResponse
    }
    $('#form_upload').ajaxSubmit(options);
</script>
```

and in server side :

```
if ('id_HeadImage' in request.FILES) and (request.FILES['id_HeadImage']):
    gForm=GalleryForm(request.FILES['id_HeadImage'],instance=newsInstance.gallery_ptr)
    if gForm.is_valid():
       gForm.save()
```

as U can see I'm going to edit ImageField of a model named `Gallery`
but this way I just get the file name.

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

this is Gallery Model:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
   HeadImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery",blank=True,null=True)
```

**EDIT**

Request.FILES is empty and ajax just post file name,not data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the **name attribute** of your file input
2. Instanciate the [form **with request.POST and request.FILES**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs#basic-file-uploads) as such: `gForm=GalleryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=newsInstance.gallery_ptr)`

Also this:

```
if ('id_HeadImage' in request.FILES) and (request.FILES['id_HeadImage']):
```

Could be more *pythonic*:

```
if 'id_HeadImage' in request.FILES.keys():
```

Comment: tnx buddy,I set the name attribute to 'id_HeadImage',like ID attribute.It didn't work!have I missed anything?

Comment: How do you think that GalleryForm should know that the file with name id_HeadImage belong to the "HeadImage" field ? You should paste the full code of your view because it looks like you're not [displaying the form in the template right](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#displaying-a-form-using-a-template)

Comment: Gallery just has a field named HeadImage,U know that id_HeadImage is it's correspond element in template,right?I edited the question.

Comment: If Gallery has a field named HeadImage, don't you think the form would expect to set Gallery.HeadImage to request.FILES['HeadImage'] ? That would make sense

Comment: But in this case It doesn't work,too! I've edited my question again,would U mind take a look?

Comment: oh!sorry the problem was another thing,thank U to remind me of sending request.FILES to GalleryForm.